# How to make SlidingMenu only slide content and not the ActionBar

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

I am using [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) with ActionBarSherlock in my app and the way I have implemented it is by making a `BaseActivity` which extends `SlidingFragmentActivity` ( similar to the way they showed in the [example](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/BaseActivity.java) ). Every other activity in my app extends this BaseActivity.

But currently, when I slide from the left in the App, the entire activity including the ActionBar slides. I only want the content to slide. So looking at the docs, I figured that adding this should do it: `menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);`

But I get an error for that line -

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: This SlidingMenu appears to already be attached`

Here's the onCreate function of the BaseActivity -

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(mTitleRes);

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFrag = new MenuListFragment();
            t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
            t.commit();
        } else {
            mFrag = (ListFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
        }

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

   // **** This following line causes the error  *****
        sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Should I be doing the `attachToActivity` somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually solved it by removing this from the Base activity -  `sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);`

and just adding this to the onCreate of all the inherited Activities:

`setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);`

I guess this is coming from a long line of inheritance (myActivity --> BaseActivity ---> SlidingFragmentActivity --> SherlockFragmentActivity)

Comment: I can't get this i tried the above but still i can't scroll horizontally in view pager or gallery in my fragment. Any clues ?

Answer (score 1):

You used the command line:

```
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
```

and you didn't attach the your menu because your menu is already attached.

use the command:

```
sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
```

if you create a new instance of SlidingMenu.
Like a `SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);`