# sliding Menu Android

Tags: android, css, slidingmenu

I am using this  [lib](https://github.com/jfeinstein10) for android sliding Menu work 
its slides my titlebar along with menu  like in picture

[image]

my sliding Menu Code

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        setBehindContentView(R.layout.fragment_frame);

        SlidingMenu slidingMenu = getSlidingMenu();

        slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);

        slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset); 

                                                                    // DEFAULT
        slidingMenu.setFadeEnabled(true);
        // slidingMenu.setBehindWidth(150);


        slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
```

I don't want to move title-bar along with sliding Menu , what should I do ?

Comment: I think lib doesn't support that

Comment: Then why are you using this library? Use default navigation drawer instead.

Comment: @Harry  yes you are right but at this time i have only this option

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);**

Remove this if you have already added

**slidingManager.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);**

Check these links for more help

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907491/3020568
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873036/3020568

Comment: setslidingActionbarEnabled(false) not working for me

Answer (score 0):

SLIDING_CONTENT will Slide (Excluding Action Bar)

SLIDING_WINDOW will Slide the Windows (Including Action Bar)

Try the Following Line of code on the attach of sliding menu

slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);